# How can I solve LI_LAZY_INIT_UPDATE_STATIC?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, class-visibility, spotbugs

I'm trying to initialize a `MethodHandle` for a non-public method in an upstream library.

```java
private static Method OF_METHOD;

static Method ofMethod() {
    if (OF_METHOD == null) {
        try {
            OF_METHOD = RequestObject.class.getDeclaredMethod(
                    "of", Class.class, String.class, String.class,
                    Object.class, Object.class);
            if (!OF_METHOD.isAccessible()) {
                OF_METHOD.setAccessible(true);
            }
        } catch (final NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
            throw new RuntimeException(nsme);
        }
    }
    return OF_METHOD;
}

private static MethodHandle OF_HANDLE;

static MethodHandle ofHandle() {
    if (OF_HANDLE == null) {
        try {
            OF_HANDLE = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(ofMethod());
        } catch (final ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(roe);
        }
    }
    return OF_HANDLE;
}
```

And my [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/) Bug Detecter Report says the `ofMethod()` has a [LI_LAZY_INIT_UPDATE_STATIC](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bugDescriptions.html#LI_LAZY_INIT_UPDATE_STATIC) problem.

I understand what it's saying. I see those two steps(assigning and setting accessible) are problematic in multi-threaded environment.

How can I solve the problem? Should I apply [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)?

Or should I put `ofMethod()` logic into `ofHandle()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering for my own question.

The idea of holding a lazy object reference is a bad idea.

Even with the [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java),

```
private static volatile Method OF_METHOD;

static Method ofMethod() {
    Method ofMethod = OF_METHOD;
    if (ofMethod == null) {
        synchronized (JacksonRequest.class) {
            ofMethod = OF_METHOD;
            if (ofMethod == null) {
                try {
                    ofMethod = ...;
                } catch (final NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(nsme);
                }
                if (!ofMethod.isAccessible()) {
                    ofMethod.setAccessible(true);
                }
                OF_METHOD = ofMethod;
            }
        }
    }
    return ofMethod;
}
```

Anyone can change the `accessible` state.

I ended up with following code which doesn't depend on any external variables.

```
static Method ofMethod() {
    try {
        final Method ofMethod = ...;
        if (!ofMethod.isAccessible()) {
            ofMethod.setAccessible(true);
        }
        return ofMethod;
    } catch (final NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        throw new RuntimeException(nsme);
    }
}
```